# Revalidate form after post response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

The setup is as follows.

1. All fields are filled out and form is valid.
2. Submit is executed, BUT there are a server side check on the
   provided data, and it returns "error, duplicate found".
3. A hidden (ng-hide is used here) input field is now shown and this
   field is set to required.
4. Now the  **problem**  occurs. The submit button is still enabled, even though the form is invalid!

Question is, how can I revalidate/update the validation state for the form after the serial number field is shown?
I have tried with the following without any luck;

```
if (status == 413) {
    $scope.hide_serial_number = false;
    if ($scope.hide_serial_number == false) {
       document.getElementById("serial_no").required = true;
       $scope.myForm.serial_no.$invalid();
    };
};
```

status code 413 = duplicate was found in DB.

My submit button;

```
<div class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-success btn-lg">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Please no jQuery answers, I'm doing all plain javascript – Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of angular? From memory, there where changes with form validation somewhere in 1.3.*

Comment: @cheekybastard using AngularJS v1.3.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it's working!

Okay, so on the error promise I was given as explained in the question, I did the following;

```
if (status == 413) {
     $scope.myForm.$invalid = true;
     document.getElementById("serial_no").required = true;
     $scope.hide_serial_number = false;
};
```

This makes the submit button disabled and waits for the serial number to be entered before enabling.